# jquery .data works in IE but not chrome or firefox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have some markup like this:

```
<li id="myId" data-foo="Bar">Text</li>
```

In IE, I am succesfully getting the value of `data-foo` with `$('#myId').data('foo')`, but it is not returning anything in Chrome or Firefox.

For what it's worth info:
The page is generated by asp.net mvc from a template.
 The function that is trying to access `data-foo` is called from a popup launched from the page containing the `<li>` element above. 
 I have also tried `$('#myId').attr('data-foo')` with no luck either

Thanks for any help you can offer

**UPDATE**
The issue is strictly related to trying to access the attribute after a popup has been launched.

**UPDATE 2** I have been unable to isolate the issue in order to duplicate it in jsfiddle. I said above that it was strictly related to accessing the attribute after a popup had been launched, but upon further investigation, that is not the case. There are several frameworks being used, and I do not have the time to search through all of them for the bug, so I have found a workaround. I just wanted to thank everyone for their efforts, and give upvotes all around for taking up your time.

Comment: There is no issue with the code you have posted. Can you provide an example where it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Could you provide a http://jsfiddle.net illustrating thr problem?

Comment: Are you sure that you only have one and only one element on the page with the id of "myId". IE behaves differently than Chrome and FF when dealing with multiple elements on the same page with the same id.  As you know, it's against the spec to share an ID but IE is usually more forgiving in this respect (but only to kick you for it later)

Comment: Yes, the id is unique. I will try and create a fiddle that fails in Chrome.

Comment: Are you SURE the ID of the element is not being changed by ASP while it is rendering your page? While building the webpage, ASP.NET will often change the ID attribute of elements it interacts with. You may want to try "View source" of your page in the browser and make sure the ID you're targeting is still what you expect it to be.

Comment: @smclark89 yes, I'm sure, but thank you.  The issue is strictly related to trying to access the attribute after a popup has been launched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me in Chrome and Firefox.

[Here is my test](http://jsfiddle.net/DpjKE/)...

```
<ul>
    <li id="myId" data-foo="Bar">Text</li>
</ul>
<script>
    alert($('#myId').data('foo'));
</script>
```

The most likely reason this may fail is that you are running your jQuery before the element is loaded, so make sure your script is at the end of the document, or uses the `$(document).ready(` syntax to ensure the DOM is ready to be queried.

I used jQuery 1.9 to test this.

Comment: thanks for your time and answer, but my jQuery is running after the element is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I notice you're using this on a list item. Can you confirm with absolute certainty that your IDs are unique? That could cause some different unexpected results across browsers.

**EDIT:** Syntactical errors in your HTML are the primary cause of these kinds of issues. I'd recommend deleting portions of your HTML code piece by piece until it works as expected and then you can identify where the issue is.